# storing date and time value through SQL LOADER

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime-format, sql-loader, controlfile

I am trying to write a control file for a sql loader.
The source file to which is in fixed length format.
I have date and time present in the source file like say , from position 17 to position 24 for date in `CCYYMMDD` format and from position 25 to 34 in `HH:MM:SS24` format.
I like to store this date and time value form source file in a date column in some table in 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS' format.

Can Anybody please help in telling how to achieve this in control file of sql loader?

Would following piece of code do? I doubt since there is no space between the date and time in the source file?

```
APPEND INTO TABLE target_table
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
date_column POSITION(17:34) "TO_DATE(:DATE_TIME,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')"
)
```

Any lead would be highly appreciated

Comment: This should work.  Remove the space though, the format should match the data in the file.  Try it and see!

Answer (score 0):

Check [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_field_list.htm#i1008756) `BOUNDFILLER:`

```
...
(date_column BOUNDFILLER POSITION(17:24), 
 time_column BOUNDFILLER POSITION(25:34), 
 date_n_time POSITION(1:1) 
             TO_DATE(:date_column || ' ' || :time_column, 'CCYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'),
 ...
)
```

It allows you to define fields that do not correspond to any column.